# Excel Summing Sequences?

Tags: excel, sum

I'm trying to do sequential summing on a spreadsheet.
The first rows are data by date, and I want do sums by the week. but Excel's autopopulate keeps screwing it up and I don't know how to fix that.

```
Date  A
----
1  |  5
2  |  5
3  |  5
4  |  5
5  |  5
6  |  5
7  |  5
8  |  5 
9  |  5
10 |  5
11 |  5
12 |  5
13 |  5
14 |  5
```

so what I want in another area

```
Week  Total
  1 | =sum(A1:A7)
  2 | =sum(A8:A14)
  3 | =sum(A15:A21)
  4 | continue like this for 52 weeks
```

but what excel keeps giving me with it's auto populating is

```
Week  Total
  1 | =sum(A1:A7) #The first iteration
  2 | =sum(A2:A8) #auto generated
  3 | =sum(A3:A9) #auto generated
```

How can I get excel to give me the results I want here? I've been searching on summing for a while and can't seem to even phrase my question right.

Comment: Is your Date column really just numbers, or is it actual dates?

Comment: @TimWilliams it's dates, for simplicity of typing out a sample table, i ignored them.

Comment: OK that doesn't help us much with getting you a useful answer  though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=sum(indirect("A"&(row()*7-6)&":A"&(row()*7)))
```

pasted in row 1 and below should work
at least in sheets, it does. (and excel docs say indirect works)

Comment: I assumed your things to sum are in column "A". IF dates are in column A and things to sum are in B, replace "A" with "B" and ":A" with ":B"

Comment: and if you have that header row, change my row() to (row()-1)

Comment: yeah I have a header row, and it's working. Messy, but works.

Comment: Glad it is working. Someone out there might come up with something more elegant.